# Can't view contents of Documents or subfolders/file with CLI only

Tags: finder, command-line, permission

I do a moderate amount with the command line but have inadvertently done something that confuses me.

I needed to download the contents of a webpage with wget so I did this:

`wget -P -r ~/Documents/sites/ds_site https://www.examplewebsite.org/`

That apparently has changed my permissions for the folder. Or so it would *seem*. When I `cd` to the site, once I get past Documents, autocompletion stops. I can finish the folder path (ds_site in this case). But when I try to check the file contents, I get the following message:

`ls: .: Operation not permitted`

However, there are no issues with seeing, opening, creating or removing a file or subfolder *while using Finder*. Just cli and only for under the Documents folder.

**What I've done.**
Checked for permissions both with Finder

[image]

and with the command line. The file shown is just to illustrate the problem is also for files, not just subfolders. Again, this is fine in Finder.

[image]

Any ideas of how I can fix this?

Comment: Add `Terminal.app` or `iTerm2.app` to the `Full Disk Access` permission panel.

Comment: That did it but I'd like to know why. LIke, why that was the fix and what caused the break. That, and have it as an answer so I could accept and upvote it.

Comment: It's because of the personal information protection layer ("Transparency, Consent, and Control" or TCC) in recent versions of macOS. See ['Why do I get "ls: Desktop: Operation not permitted" when I own Desktop?'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/425519/why-do-i-get-ls-desktop-operation-not-permitted-when-i-own-desktop) and ["What and how does macOS Mojave implement to restrict applications access to personal data?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers)

Comment: You can try reset permission on your User with this terminal command  : `diskutil resetuserpermissions / $(id -u)`