# What additional features controls file permission?

Tags: macos, permission

I have a file if I put it in /tmp, I can read or write to it. But if I move to ~/Downloads, I can not read or write to it.

But the permission of the file is `-rw-r--r--`. Is there any additional permission used by Mac but accessible by `ls`? How to check this additional permission?

Comment: Who is the owner of the file? Which specific error do you get?

Comment: See ["What and how does macOS Mojave implement to restrict applications access to personal data?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers) and ["Why do I get 'ls: Desktop: Operation not permitted' when I own Desktop?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/425519/why-do-i-get-ls-desktop-operation-not-permitted-when-i-own-desktop)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Downloads, Documents, and Desktop are special folders, to which additional privileges must be granted for any app that wants to use them. You can also give an app "Full Disk Access" in System Settings > Privacy & Security.