# How can I get Jenkins to access to files on an external drive

Tags: macos, external-disk, monterey, java

My jenkins server is running on macOS Monterey, I believe this is important because my older server on macOS Catalina has no such issue.

I have some files on an external drive which I can access and use via the terminal without any issues but when I attempt to access them via the jenkins shell I get an "Operation not permitted" error.

In this test job I can list the volumes but cannot list the contents of /Volumes/TOSHIBA

This is my Jenkins job output showing "Operation not permitted" in response to an ls command on a remote volume:

```
Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/TEST
[TEST] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/8s/cg63pnc957vd9w0njmncpymw0000gp/T/jenkins11405831661869547820.sh
+ ls /Volumes
Macintosh HD
TOSHIBA
+ ls /Volumes/TOSHIBA
ls: /Volumes/TOSHIBA: Operation not permitted
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

What I've tried so far:

- Running job as jenkins user with "sudo su jenkins"
- Using a symbolic link to sneak into the external drive directory from a local path
- Changing the jenkins default shell from sh to zsh
- Adding full disk access in the mac "Security & Privacy" settings to: java, jshell, jenkins, and jenkins-cli.

Still "Operation not permitted" in every case

Comment: What does ls show in a plain terminal. (I would quote the exact command but I can't copy it from an image)

Comment: It appears that you’re opening a new *Bourne* (not Badh) shell and then running `ls`.  Now, my “off the top of the head” guess is this is a permissions issue.  Try running the command prepended with `sudo`. (Not `sudo su` as it’s redundant)

Comment: Same error:
`+ sudo ls /Volumes/TOSHIBA
ls: /Volumes/TOSHIBA: Operation not permitted`

Comment: If you stop the Jenkins server, can you `ls` that mount point?

Comment: Also, is [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/457275/119271) related to this?

Comment: I can `ls` the mount point in a terminal without any issues with the server running or not. And yes I think that question might be related, however I've tried giving jenkins full-disk access and it still can't see my external drive. I'm looking into if there is another tool being used that will also need full-disk access granted